# Java volatile keyword behaviour changes due to remove local variable

Tags: java, volatile

From the [link](https://dzone.com/articles/java-volatile-keyword-0), it provide a demo of the java keyword 'volatile'. The demo code works fine. But I try to do a little modification. the behaviour is defferent.

My code :

```
public class VolatileTest4 {

    private static int MY_INT = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ChangeListener().start();
        new ChangeMaker().start();
    }

    static class ChangeListener extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (MY_INT < 5) {
                System.out.println("Got Change for MY_INT : " + MY_INT);
            }
        }
    }

    static class ChangeMaker extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            while (MY_INT < 5) {
                System.out.println("Incrementing MY_INT to " + MY_INT);
                MY_INT++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I do is just remove the local variable of local_value.
The post says 'Without the volatile keyword, the change listener loop infinitely'. 
But My code is Without the volatile keyword, the change listener ends normally.

What is the defference? what cause the change listener end?

Comment: volatile guarantees that you will see the writes from another thread. That is very different from saying that non-volatile guarantees you won't see the writes. I can reproduce the problem by removing all the System.out.println() calls from your code, and just adding one after the while loop of the ChangeListener.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I mode all the System.out.println to the outer of the while loop, the problem occurs.   Is it possible to look at the assembler code when java code is running? Are there any tools  monitoring on the cpu level to find out the details?

Answer (score 1):

I've compared the code you've provided to the code in the article and there are substantive differences. Having modified and run the code from the article in the manner described by the author, I was able to replicate his results. My code is as follows:

```
public class VolatileTest {

    private static int MY_INT = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ChangeListener().start();
        new ChangeMaker().start();
    }

    static class ChangeListener extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int local_value = MY_INT;
            while ( local_value < 5){
                if( local_value!= MY_INT){
                    System.out.println(String.format("Got Change for MY_INT : %S", MY_INT));
                    local_value= MY_INT;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static class ChangeMaker extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run() {

            int local_value = MY_INT;
            while (MY_INT <5){
                System.out.println(String.format("Incrementing MY_INT to %S", local_value+1));
                MY_INT = ++local_value;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `volatile` keyword changes a variable's visibility semantics. Changes to a member marked `volatile` become visible to all threads after the write operation completes. *However*, the absence of `volatile` *doesn't* mean that the changes *won't* be visible. `volatile` provides some certainty around visibility; without it, you can't be sure when changes made to a value will become visible in other threads, if ever.

The author is trying to make the point that because the variable is not marked `volatile` the changes made by the `ChangeMaker` are not visible to the `ChangeReader` and in turn, the `ChangeListener` never terminates. See [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06197/) article for a better treatment of the `volatile` keyword.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The link you provided is useful. What are the substantive differences? I mentioned that the code in article works fine. I replace the logger with System.out. Also, I remove the local variable 'local_value'. I think if there is no local variable, the code should get the same result as the article, but It's not.